# How to make a timeline in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I've a several task series like this on several day in Google Sheet:

```
|Task 1     |03/08/2021 03:00:03    |03/08/2021 03:10:05|
|Task 2     |03/08/2021 05:00:03    |03/08/2021 05:21:37|
|Task 3     |03/08/2021 11:20:03    |03/08/2021 11:34:42|
|Task 4     |03/08/2021 06:20:01    |03/08/2021 07:43:12|
|Task 5     |03/08/2021 03:30:02    |03/08/2021 04:09:10|
```

I would like to make a timeline like this picture below  in Google Sheet.
It was easier to make a timeline with a JSON than Google Sheet.

[image]

May be I could insert the code in Google Sheet but I don't know how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the list of charts that you can insert in Google Sheets: [Types of charts & graphs in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/190718).

The closer chart to what you are looking is the [stacked bar chart](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9142829#zippy=%2Cstacked-bar-chart). You might add two series, one for the gap from the chart start date to the task start date, then set this bar to have no borders, no labels, have the same background color than the chart, the other series for the tasks.

Regarding using JSON to create a chart, Google Sheets doesn't support that directly but you could use Google Apps Script to insert a chart to the spreadsheet, among other things.

Comment: but we can ingest data from Google Sheet https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets#gid I'm going to dig that